# Can't display the uploaded image laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload image to display it in view, but when I try to display it, it doesn't show on image section of my view.

I already have symlink, and it works. I can see my uploaded image in 'public/storage/images' path.
It also shows up on 'storage\app\public\images' path.

**My code to display the image**

```
@if(filled($book->image))
<img src="{{asset($book->image)}}" style="width: 8%;height:8%">
```

**My code for the image upload**

```
if ($request->hasFile('book_image')) {
    $book->image = $request->file('book_image')->storeAs('public/images', $request->id . '.' . $request->file('book_image')->getClientOriginalExtension());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `src="{{ url('/images/'.$book->image) }}"`

Comment: Write your image full path

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the image url in blade then you can use url helper like `img src="{{ url('storage/app/public/images/'.$filename) }}"`

or elsewhere like

`storage_path('/app/public/images/' . $filename)`

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code like this

```
<img src="{{asset('images/'.$book->image)}}" style="width:8%; height:8%">
```

This should work if you already run `storage:link` in your command line